# Unable to update a timezone using Timezone Updater Tool for a version 2016g

Tags: java, timezone

This issue is not related to [missing version information issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166928).

After I have created a modified `tzdata2016g.tar.gz` (as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#issues)), I'm trying to update time zones:

```
$ sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -l file:///tmp/tzupdater-2.1.0/tzdata2016g.tar.gz
```

but I have an exception. The output of the command above is following:

```
Using file:///tmp/tzupdater-2.1.0/tzdata2016g.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_101
tzupdater version 2.1.0-b04
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2016d
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata.tar.gz
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata2016g/northamerica (Not a directory)
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata2016g/northamerica (Not a directory)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata2016g/northamerica (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.extractFiles(ExternalModule.java:103)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:209)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:643)
```

If I put data to `/tmp/tz.tmp/tzdata2016g` manually, `tzupdater` tries to create `/tmp/tz.tmp_1/tzdata2016g` with the same exception at the end.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Could you perhaps add the structure of your tzdata2016g.tar.gz file. I think you probably added root directory to the archive that is not expected by tzupdater...

Comment: You are absolutely right. Please, post your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you probably added a root directory to the archive that is not expected by tzupdater. The structure of the source tzdata file downloaded from https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2016g.tar.gz looks like this:

```
$ tar --list -zf tzdata2016g.tar.gz
CONTRIBUTING
...
australasia
europe
northamerica
...
leapseconds.awk
zoneinfo2tdf.pl
```

That is all files need to be directly in the archive's root.

Comment: Spent close to 4 hours, after finally stumbling on this page/answer. Great help !